# python re.search pattern with square braces and text

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python Regex and regex is not my strong suite. so
I have a text line e.g.
' the lazy brown fox "jump" over [txt_1234] '
next line
'sky is falling'

the second line is therefore None.

its exactly as I write it.

1. I need to extract the txt_1234 part only. no braces
2. Also the result must begin with txt other '[]' if present should be ignored
3. If [txt_* is not present it should be None ofcourse
   Looks like I would be using search instead of match.

sounds easy I know, i just can't get it right.

Comment: I tried (?<=\[)\w+?(?=\]) but when trying to make sure txt_ i included i was getting none.

Comment: `but when trying to make sure txt_ i included i was getting none` Can you post the exact code you tried? It would help me see where your error is if I could see your code.

Comment: ok I think this works (?<=\[)txt_.\w+?(?=\]) testing to see if it does ignore non txt_
i was placing the txt_ wrong in my regex
edit: yes that works. I believe alex could fix his regex as well to exclude the braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex will be...

```
\[(txt_.*?)\]
```

Comment: yes that works. thanks. How do I get the value of the match. Edit: ok got it with group(0), however it includes the '[]' which I wanted to exlcude.

Comment: I have added my own test above (?<=\[)\w+?(?=\]) , this does exclude braces but I need to ensure that txt_ is rpesent.

Comment: @Vangel Use the regex I provided, it ensures that `txt_` is present inside the brackets.

Comment: @Vangel Look at the first capturing group.